Why is there a sudden drop at the rest initial point after discharging? (trying to find IR Drop of LIC)
I'm trying to get IR drop of one of my LIC cells.
After discharge, at the initial point of rest, I believe there should be a sudden increase in the voltage due to resistance.
Does anybody know why is there a sudden decrease in the voltage at 0.725hr?


What time is the 'initial point of rest'. Show a schematic for your cell, load, and measurement connections, indicating any long leads with a small resistor. What do you do to the cell at 0.733 hrs?

Probably because the point where you measure the voltage is not at the cell terminals, it's closer to an inductive load, and it is affected by the current and the voltage spike on the inductive load when it's turned off. Or, the load has a bug that results in a sudden increase in the load current as it's turned off, before it actually turns off.
